# apt-get upgrade overwrites build configurations

Tags: apt, upgrade

I installed GraphicsMagick with some modified configurations, different from those of the repository package, and then I ran `apt-get upgrade`, just to see that the changes I made were reset to defaults. Is that how it goes? And if so, how can I tell it to not overwrite my configs?

EDIT: I rebuilt the package with `debuild` and then installed with `dpkg -i`, in case that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you say "modified configurations", do you mean you added some config files in `/etc/somewhere`, or that you compiled the package with different options?

If the former, then those files, if declared as configuration files, should not be touched when upgrading, as per Debian policy: http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-files.html.

If the latter, then well yes, apt-get is doing what you ask: it's entirely upgrading the package (and all its binaries) with a new version. If you want to exclude a package from the upgrade process (rather, if you want to *keep* a specific version of a package regardless of whether an updated version is available), then you need to "pin" the package. See more about pinning here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto

Comment: Yes, it was the latter, and the problem is, it's not one package if I'm getting it right, this upgrade for instance was for something like perlmagick and a couple of others, and so now I have to "pin" them all too? And another thing, is it ok to "pin" them, nothing funny would happen?

Comment: To be 100% sure, you should pin any packages that you modified. Pinning is safe, you're just keeping those versions without change, the only chance for something "funny" is if a package has an update that depends on a newer version of imagemagick; it just wouldn't be applied because it would require a new imagemagick, which you specified (via the pinning mechanism) that you don't want.